# Unable to execute Admin Login in Postman

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, authentication, postman

I m trying to create a login function for admin in postman but unable to get the required output for correct credentials.

this is Login Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "Welcome to ABC Bank login page";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/login", consumes = "application/json", produces ="application/json")
    public String display(@RequestBody String userId, String password,Model m){
        //System.out.println("Please Login");
    System.out.println("userId" + userId);
    if(userId.equals("admin") && password.equals("root")) {
        return "Welcome to ABC Bank";
    }else {
        return "Login UnSuccessful ";
    }
    
    }
```

This is Login model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login_page")
public class Login {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_Id", nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
  // @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
  // @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
   // @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    

}
```

Thus I need to execute the Welcome to ABC bank when admin logins with correct credentials.
How can I do it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1cvN.png)

Comment: The way you are receiving the data in the api is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public String display(@RequestBody String userId, String password,Model m){}
```

I would consider doing something like

```
public String display(@RequestBody LoginRequest request){}
```

This can be further enhanced with a map of headers and tokens for security.